# Stretch value range via formula?

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization

I have values between 0 and 1.

What I want to do is to convert them according the following rules :

```
if v < 0.5 then v *= 2
if v > 0.5 then v = (v-0.5)*2
if v = 0.5 then v = 1
```

Now the question is how to do this in a formula without using conditions ?

---

I got it .. i need this

```
In [487]: v
Out[487]: array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])

In [488]: 1-abs(0.5-v)*2
Out[488]: array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0. ])
```

What I'm trying to do is to stretch the range 0-0.5 to 0-1 and the range 0.5-1 to 0-1

---

couldnt find a good tag for this question ;(

Comment: That function is not continuous at $x=0.5$. For example, $f(0.50)=1$ and $f(0.51)=0.2$ The condition is unavoidable.

Comment: what if we exclude the last rule ? and add the = to one of the other

Comment: The third rule can be included in the first rule. It's the second one who sets the discontinuity.

Comment: ok :) what if i accept it to be undef/nan/inf for 0.5

Comment: Seems you're asking a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Why do you need to expand two ranges into the same destination?

Comment: The [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) $\{2v\}$ almost gives what you want, except that for $v=\frac12$ we have $\{2v\}=0$, not $1$.